# Need help on simplify a list of strings

Tags: android, string, list

Can someone help me on simplfy this lists of strings:

```
public class MyList {

    // New customers
    public static final String mNew1 = "email1";
    public static final String mNew2 = "email2";
    public static final String mNew3 = "email3";
    public static final String mNew4 = "email4";

    // Old customers
    public static final String mOld1 = "email1";
    public static final String mOld2 = "email2";
    public static final String mOld3 = "email3";
}
```

---

```
public class App extends Application {
    public static boolean mIsNew = false;
    public static boolean mIsOld = false;

Pattern emailPattern = Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS;
        Account[] accounts = AccountManager.get(context).getAccounts();
        for (Account account : accounts) {
            if (emailPattern.matcher(account.name).matches()) {
                String possibleEmail = account.name;
                if (MyList.mNew1.matches(possibleEmail) || MyList.mNew2.matches(possibleEmail) ||
                        MyList.mNew3.matches(possibleEmail) || MyList.mNew4.matches(possibleEmail)) {
                    mIsNew = true;
                }
                if (MyList.mOld1.matches(possibleEmail) || MyList.mOld2.matches(possibleEmail) || MyList.mOld3.matches(possibleEmail)) {
                    mIsOld = true;
                }
            }
        }
```

Since the old customers email will be over 10.000 in less then a week can you suggest me an easy way to pick the strings from the MyList class and enable the right boolean? I.E if oneOfTheStringInThisList.matches(possibleEmail) mIsOld = true.

I'm not really familiar with lists of strings, sorry for my noob question! Thankyou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values by reflection:

```
private void Something()
{
    MyList list = new MyList();
    HashSet<String> oldMails = new HashSet<String>();
    HashSet<String> newMails = new HashSet<String>();
    try {
        GetAllMails(list, oldMails, newMails);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        // TODO
    }

    boolean mIsOld = oldMails.contains("email4");
    boolean mIsNew = newMails.contains("email4");
}

private void GetAllMails(MyList list, HashSet<String> oldMails, HashSet<String> newMails) throws IllegalAccessException
{
    Field[] allFields = MyList.class.getDeclaredFields();   
    for(Field f : allFields)
    {
        if (f.getName().startsWith("mNew"))
        {
            newMails.add(f.get(list).toString());
        }
        else if (f.getName().startsWith("mOld"))
        {
            oldMails.add(f.get(list).toString());
        }
    }
}
```

You should store the HashSets in memory because reflection is not very performant.

Comment: with this way i have to add the emails 2 times! isn't there a way to add all the mails in a sort of lists and do a single check on the list?

Comment: Do you really have 10000 E-Mail addresses as hardcoded strings in your app?

Comment: had to tweak it a little but yes... this is exactly the solution i was looking for! Thanks mate!